# How do I do binding in a Visual Studio extension a Stackpanel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017, xaml-binding

I am writing a Visual Studio extension, which does not seem relevant, but perhaps it is. My code is throwing an exception in the codebehind when the initializeComponent is being called. I have a TeamExplorerSection which creates a "model" and passes it to the SectionView (the xaml) in the constructor. It is stored as a property of the view. The model has some properties, Name, Id etc. I am able to bind these properties to the view, but it also has a collection which I am trying to bind to an ItemsControl sitting in a stackpanel. This does not work.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ReviewPlus.ReviewPlusTeamExplorerSectionView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:ReviewPlus.ViewModels="clr-namespace:ReviewPlus.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="250" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ReviewPlus.ViewModels:RelatedReviewsViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>    
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl Name="RelatedReviewsICtl" ItemsSource="{Binding RelatedReviews}">
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">                 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PreviousId}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>    
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the exception:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
>     HResult=0x80131501
>     Message='Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception.' Line number '22' and line position '19'.
>     Source=PresentationFramework
>     StackTrace:
>      at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
>      at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
>      at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
>      at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
>      at ReviewPlus.TeamExplorerSectionView.InitializeComponent() in C:\Dev\ReviewPlus\ReviewPlus\CodePlusTeamExplorerSectionView.xaml:line 1
>   Inner Exception 1:
>   InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

I seem to be doing something wrong with this binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XAML is adding `DataTemplate`as an item, hence the error. You need to specify that it's the `ItemTemplate`. Try this.

```
<ItemsControl Name="RelatedReviewsICtl" ItemsSource="{Binding RelatedReviews}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">                 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PreviousId}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The difference is that `DataTemplate` is within the `ItemTemplate`setter.